# Typedef 'NSAlertStyle' cannot be referenced with a enum specifier

Tags: swift, objective-c, xcode, compiler-errors

Semantic Issue:

It works fine with other Xcode version, facing this issue for Xcode14.0.1

- This is the Swift Bridging header file and Here is the method defination where the error comes from:-

> (void)showModalAlertWithTitle:(NSString * _Nonnull)title message:(NSString * _Nonnull)message informativeText:(NSString * _Nonnull)informativeText style:(enum NSAlertStyle)style completionHandler:(void (^ _Nonnull)(NSModalResponse))completionHandler;

Since it works in other projects, I guess something is wrong in my project build settings ?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this.

The problem for me was that my project was set to compile with the default C++ dialect of the compiler, which I think is C++98.

The generated Swift headers only work with newer C++ dialects. I changed the "C++ Language Dialect" in my project's "Build Settings" to "C++20" and the error was resolved.